# Excel vba activecell.value as integer

Tags: excel, vba

I want to set the value of the active cell as Yaxis2, but I can't find how to do this.

```
    Dim yaxis2 as integer
    ActiveCell.Value = Yaxis2
```

This was my attempt, but it didn't work.

Comment: an integer, wow I completely forgot to mention that. (Fixed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to set it to the string you need to wrap it in double quotes(").

```
 ActiveCell.Value ="Yaxis2"
```